# how to set up phpredis for php 7.2

Tags: php, windows, redis, phpredis

I would like to ask is there anyone knows how to set up the phpradis in Laravel with the PHP version of 7.2?

I already set up radis in my project but did not manage to set up phpradis. I am using Windows and the instructions or resources for setting up phpradis in Windows on the Internet are outdated. I hope I can get some help from here.

I already downloaded the extension from PECL and move php_redis.dll and php_igbinary.dll to the ext directory. I also modify my php.ini and added in these 3 lines:

```
;php_redis
extension=php_igbinary.dll
extension=php_redis.dll
```

Any steps did I miss out here?